# "unexpected nil value for service tag information" when using data.azurerm_network_service_tags

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm getting the following error when using the `data.azurerm_network_service_tags` terraform data source:

```
Error: unexpected nil value for service tag information

  on main.tf line 171, in data "azurerm_network_service_tags" "sqlservicetags":
 171: data "azurerm_network_service_tags" "sqlservicetags" {
```

My code looks like this:

```
data "azurerm_network_service_tags" "sqlservicetags" {
  location        = "UK South"
  service         = "Sql"
  location_filter = "uksouth"
}
```

I tried this exact same code on another Azure account and it works fine, so there must be something different in the accounts which causes this error, though I cannot figure it out.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hello @cdcdimitroulas, may I know if both accounts are of same offer type ? what is the offer type as well..

Comment: also can you try getting the service tags using other methods as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview#use-the-service-tag-discovery-api

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT what is the offer type? Where do I see that?

Comment: from portal , you can search on the top bar subscriptions and then select the subscription and verify if both the subscription offer and offer id

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I don't have the permission to view those fields in the problematic Azure account with my user. In the other account those fields aren't there (I'm assuming because it's a free trial account with credit)

Comment: may i know what is the permission level you have in that subscription ?

Comment: I don't seem to have a way to view it but I think you're right that it's probably a permissions issue. I've put in a request to the folks who manage those for the Azure subscription to add the `Microsoft.Network/locations/*/serviceTags/read` action to the list of permissions

Comment: yeah correct .. even if they provide you contributor access it should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments please check the ***Permission Level*** you have in the problematic subscription with your admin.

You need to have `Contributor` access on the subscription or `Network Contributor`  access to be able to view the required details in the subscription. If providing Contributor level access is difficult for the admin , then you can also create a ***[custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles)*** with actions `Microsoft.Network/locations/serviceTagDetails/read` to   ***get Service Tag details*** & `Microsoft.Network/locations/serviceTags/read` to   ***get Service Tags*** on the required subscription.

For more details on ***`Built-in Roles`*** or ***`Resource Provider Opertaions`*** you can refer this ***[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)***.

Comment: And to add, seems there's no built-in role that include these 2 permissions without having other potentital unwanted actions. So you might need to come up with a custom role.